# Why is thread ceremony not performed for girls?

Tags: rituals

There were many women in  ancient times who became sages in their own right.

Why then was sacred thread ceremony not prescribed, at least for some girls willing to follow any recommended strict restrictions?

Have there been some exceptions anywhere or at anytime?